# How to create New Rdd with all possible combination of elements other Rdd in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Hi i have created a Rdd like below

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize(['P','T','K'])
rdd1.collect()
['P', 'T', 'K']
```

Now I want to create new `RDD2` with all possible combinations like below  with new RDD.i.e.except  same element combination like(p,p),(k,k),(t,t).

my expected output when i am doing

```
RDD2.collect()

[
    ('P'),('T'),('K'),
    ('P','T'),('P','K'),('T','K'),('T','P'),('K','P'),('K','T'),
    ('P','T','K'),('P','K','T'),('T','P','K'),('T','K','P'),('K','P','T'),('K','T','P')
]
```

Comment: You need a `crossJoin` and filter. Probably something like `rdd.crossJoin(rdd).filter(lambda row: row[0] != row[1])`. This can be generalized for more combinations.

Comment: i am getting error like "AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'crossJoin'"

Comment: i have tried rdd2=rdd1.cartesian(rdd1) but it is not giving all combinations.

Comment: You intend to do that for more than 3 values I guess, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to generate all permutations of the elements in your `rdd` where each row contains unique values.

One way would be to first create a helper function to generate the desired combination of length `n`:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

def combinations_of_length_n(rdd, n):
    # for n > 0
    return reduce(
        lambda a, b: a.cartesian(b).map(lambda x: tuple(chain.from_iterable(x))),
        [rdd]*n
    ).filter(lambda x: len(set(x))==n)
```

Essentially the function will do `n` Cartesian products of your `rdd` with itself and keep only the rows where all of the values are distinct.

We can test this out for `n = [2, 3]`:

```
print(combinations_of_length_n(rdd1, n=2).collect())
#[('P', 'T'), ('P', 'K'), ('T', 'P'), ('K', 'P'), ('T', 'K'), ('K', 'T')]

print(combinations_of_length_n(rdd1, n=3).collect())
#[('P', 'T', 'K'),
# ('P', 'K', 'T'),
# ('T', 'P', 'K'),
# ('K', 'P', 'T'),
# ('T', 'K', 'P'),
# ('K', 'T', 'P')]
```

The final output that you want is just `union` of these intermediate results with the original `rdd` (with the values mapped to `tuple`s).

```
rdd1.map(lambda x: tuple((x,)))\
    .union(combinations_of_length_n(rdd1, 2))\
    .union(combinations_of_length_n(rdd1, 3)).collect()
#[('P',),
# ('T',),
# ('K',),
# ('P', 'T'),
# ('P', 'K'),
# ('T', 'P'),
# ('K', 'P'),
# ('T', 'K'),
# ('K', 'T'),
# ('P', 'T', 'K'),
# ('P', 'K', 'T'),
# ('T', 'P', 'K'),
# ('K', 'P', 'T'),
# ('T', 'K', 'P'),
# ('K', 'T', 'P')]
```

---

To generalize for any max number of repetitions:

```
num_reps = 3
reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.union(b),
    [
        combinations_of_length_n(rdd1.map(lambda x: tuple((x,))), i+1) 
        for i in range(num_reps)
    ]
).collect()
#Same as above
```

---

**Note**: Cartesian products are expensive operations and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: It's a good solution +1. Maybe you should warn the OP that it's a very expensive solution thought.

Comment: There is no way around this unfortunately. This is by definition how combination works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. You can run a loop and get permutations and store them in a list then convert list to rdd

```
>>> rdd1.collect()
['P', 'T', 'K']
>>> 
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(2,rdd1.count()+1):
...     x = list(itertools.permutations(rdd1.toLocalIterator(),i))
...     l = l+x
... 
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize(l)
>>> 
>>> rdd2.collect()
[('P', 'T'), ('P', 'K'), ('T', 'P'), ('T', 'K'), ('K', 'P'), ('K', 'T'), ('P', 'T', 'K'), ('P', 'K', 'T'), ('T', 'P', 'K'), ('T', 'K', 'P'), ('K', 'P', 'T'), ('K', 'T', 'P')]
```

Comment: This is a solution, but it won't scale. In case the OP doesn't have much data, RDD/Spark shouldn't be used then. BTW I've also found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/3415409 for plain python.

Comment: Hi i had given small data for easy understanding but ,OP have huge Data.